# Why do the instance variables of the object being passed in have to be accessed using the dot notation?

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void) addFractions: (Fraction*) f
{
    numerator = numerator * f.denominator
    + denominator *f.numerator;

    denominator = denominator *f.denominator;
}
```

//This is objective c-2.0

// this is the .h file for the .m above

```
-(void) addFractions : (Fraction*) f;
```

> Don’t forget that you can refer to the Fraction that is the receiver of the message by 
>   its fields:numerator and denominator.On the other hand,you can’t directly refer to the 
>   instance variables of the argument fthat way.Instead,you have to obtain them by apply- 
>   ing the dot operator to f(or by sending an appropriate message to f)

Comment: You might want to at least tell people what language you're using.

Comment: Please specify what language you're using and what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't thing any language other than obj-C has such an ugly syntax. I still shiver when I remember dev-days sometimes.

Comment: This is a method to a fractions class I'm working on. Since my method takes a Fraction object why do I have to access the instance variables of the fraction object in this way? i.e (f.numerator and f.denominator?)

Comment: Are you asking why can you not override operators as you can in C++?

Comment: How would you like the code to look?

Answer (score 2):

In order to bring both fractions to use the same denominator.

I mean, a/b+c/d = a*d/(b*d) + c*b/(d*b) = (a*d + c*b) / (b*d).

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have two fractions `p/q` and `r/s` that you'd like to add to a new fraction `a/b`. What does each line do?

```
// a = (p * s) + (q * r)
numerator = numerator * f.denominator + denominator * f.numerator;

// b = (r * s)
denominator = denominator *f.denominator;
```

Together you have:

```
 a    p * s + q * r
--- = -------------
 b        r * s
```

This is the traditional way to add two fractions with arbitrary, different denominators. Here's an example -- say you wanted to add 3/5 and 2/9:

```
 a    3 * 9 + 2 * 5   27 + 10   37
--- = ------------- = ------- = --
 b        5 * 9          45     45
```

Verifying, [**we see that this is indeed correct**](http://www.google.com/search?q=3%2F5+%2B+2%2F9+-+37%2F45&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 0):

`a.b` (a dot b) is syntactic sugar for using the member variable accessors `[a b]`, or mutators `[a setb]` when used as an lvalue.

I really don't understand what you are complaining about; this code is as clear And compact as any language is possible to be.  That's how I would write it in pseudocode, too.

The rest is just maths.

Comment: In Obj-C the getter is usually just the property name, i.e., `[a b]`.

Comment: The setter by default is `[a setB:...]`, not `[a setb]`.

Comment: I'm not confused about the math part,I understand to add fractions.
What I don't understand is wy the member variables have to be accessed using this notation " f.numerator and f.denominator" instead of accessing them directly.